# Classifying the Trajectories of Pendulum

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, chaos-theory

The equation of the pendulum is: 
$$\ddot{\theta}+\frac{g}{l}\sin\theta$$

After some manipulation, we get

$$H=\frac{\dot{\theta}^{2}}{2}-\frac{g}{l}\cos\theta=\mathrm{positive\ constant}$$

Trajectories corresponds to the solution of the equation(above). Evidently, there are three possibilities.

**1.**$$H<\frac{g}{l}$$

**2.**$$\frac{-g}{l}\leq H\leq \frac{g}{l}$$

**3.**$$H>\frac{g}{l}$$

---

**1.** For $H<\frac{g}{l}$

**(a)** When $\theta =\pm \pi$:

$$\dot{\theta}=\pm\sqrt{2(H-\frac{g}{l})} =\pm i\sqrt{2(\frac{g}{l}-H)}$$and we get real solutions.

**(b)** When $\theta$ = 0:

$$\dot{\theta}=\pm \sqrt{2(H+\frac{g}{l})}=\mathrm{real\ solution}$$

---

**2.** Now, for $\frac{-g}{l}<H<\frac{g}{l}$

**(a)** When $\frac{-g}{l}<H\ \text{and}\ \theta =\pm \pi$:

$$\dot{\theta}=\pm 2\sqrt{2(H-\frac{g}{l})}$$
Since $H>\frac{-g}{l},\ \mathrm{then}\ H-\frac{g}{l}$ is positive.
So this case corresponds to real solutions.

**(b)** When $H>\frac{g}{l}\ \text{and}\ \theta =\pm \pi$:

$$\dot{\theta}=\pm i\sqrt{2(\frac{g}{l}-H)}$$
so the solution is imaginary.

---

**3.** There is a final case $H>\frac{g}{l}$ but shall omit it.

---

How do the different cases of $H$ relate to the trajectories?

The trajectory looks like a figure 8 rotated 90 degrees either direction.

Thanks in advance.